# ¿Cómo indicar el tamaño de un Vector dentro de un Vector **cuando se declara**?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Recién estoy aprendiendo sobre vectores y una duda que me surgió es como indicar el amano de un Vector (**B**) que esta dentro de otro Vector (**A**) **cuando se declara**.

Para ser mas especifico:

```
   vector <vector <int> > i(5); //declaro el vector A y le asigno unas 5 casillas.
//    A   <   B   <int> > i(5); //pero no se como asignarle casillas al vector B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola para crear un vector de vectores nada mas necesitas lo siguiente

```
vector<vector<int> > i(dimension, vector<int>(dimension));
```

Esto te crearía un vector de vectores el cual puedes de hecho accederlo como si fuera una matriz de modo que

```
i[0][1] = 5;
```

por ejemplo sería válido